# Groovy unusual convention

Tags: groovy

I have seen strange code for many times:

```
...
private currencyFormat = NumberFormat.currencyInstance
def convert = currencyFormat.&parse
...
```

By strange I mean this -> **.&parse**. Why logical AND operator is needed and who else it can be used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a method pointer

`convert` is now effectively a Closure which delegates to the parse method

#### Example

It's [defined here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Operators#Operators-Object-RelatedOperators) without an example, and [mrhaki did a post about it here](http://mrhaki.blogspot.co.uk/2009/08/groovy-goodness-turn-methods-into.html).

And as an example showing it handles overloading, consider a class with 2 static methods:

```
class Test {
  static void printSomething( String thing ) {
    println "A:$thing"
  }

  static void printSomething( String thing, String thing2 ) {
    println "B:$thing$thing2"
  }
}
```

We can get a reference to the `printSomething` methods:

```
def ref = Test.&printSomething
```

And then we can pass it to an `each` call on a list of single items:

```
// prints A:a and A:b
[ 'a', 'b' ].each ref
```

Or we can pass it two items and it will pick the correct overloaded method to call:

```
// prints B:ab and B:cd
[ [ 'a', 'b' ], [ 'c', 'd' ] ].each ref
```

Comment: can you provide some examples of using method pointers? I cannot find normal materials in the Internet.

Comment: @Bob added a couple of links and an overloaded example

Answer (score 1):

It's not a bit manipulation operator. The ampersand was probably chosen because that's what C's address operator uses. The idea is that you can pass around references to a method on a specific instance.

Say you have some logic like:

```
def stuff = null
if (condition) {
    stuff = foo.doThis(a, b, c)
} else {
    stuff = bar.doOther(a, b, c)
}
```

You can rewrite that with a method pointer like this:

```
def myMethod = condition ? foo.&doThis : bar.&doOther
def stuff = myMethod(a, b, c)
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't mean `and`. It's special syntax to reuse a method as a closure. Now you can use `convert` in places where you can pass a closure, like `grep`, `find` or similar methods.